# WriteAllText replaces all text anyway t

Tags: c#

```
public static void checktxt(string wor, int mutatevoorraad, int idmutate)
{
    var data = File
         .ReadAllLines("../../../test.txt")
         .Select(x => x.Split('='))
         .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
         .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1]);

   int items = Convert.ToInt32(data["items"]);

   items2 = items;

   switch (wor)
   {
       case "write":
            for (int i = 1; i <= items; i++)
                 {
                    Console.WriteLine("ID:               {0}", data["id" + i]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Merk:             {0}", data["make" + i]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Model:            {0}", data["model" + i]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Opslag in MBs:    {0}", data["mbsize" + i]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Prijs:            {0}", data["price" + i]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Voorraad:         {0}", data["storage" + i]);
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                 }
              Console.ReadLine();
              break;
       case "mutate":
              int mutatevoorraad2 = mutatevoorraad + Convert.ToInt32(data["storage" + idmutate]);

              if (mutatevoorraad2 >= 0)
              {
                  string pass2 = "storage" + idmutate;
                  string text = File.ReadAllText(@"../../../test.txt");
                  text = text.Replace(data[pass2], " " + mutatevoorraad2.ToString());
                  File.WriteAllText(@"../../../test.txt", text);

                  Console.Clear();               
                  Console.WriteLine("Succesvol gemuteerd");
                  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
              }
              else
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("U heeft een negatieve mutatie gedaan probeer het opnieuw!");
                  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                  MP3speler.mutate();
              }

              break;
       default:
           break;
   }


}
```

How can I replace one part off text?

My text file looks like this:

```
id = 1
name = internet
storage = 6

id = 2 
name = technologies
storage = 6
```

Im using writealltext now but if i want to change 6 for id 1 it will change it for both off them does anyone know how to be able to change 1 part?

```
string pass2 = data["storage" + idmutate];
string pass = "storage" + idmutate + " =" + pass2;
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"../../../test.txt");
text = text.Replace(pass, "storage" + idmutate + " = " + mutatevoorraad2.ToString());
File.WriteAllText(@"../../../test.txt", text);
```

This works.

Comment: Fixed it by changing code to read full line and change it.

Comment: Post that as an answer

Comment: Well thats not possible because of my reputation i have to wait 8 hours.

Comment: so your question solved ya? give the correct asnwer and mark your answer as accepted?